# catching error in fetch not working properly

Tags: javascript, error-handling, fetch, es6-promise

I am learning about fetch and promises. This was the example I was given:

```
  fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) { // res.ok <- is undefined and I suspect this is the problem
      throw new Error(res.error); // this should fire of if there is an error
    }
    return res;
  })
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

It catches the error even though there is no error. This code above should throw an error if there is and error (if the status is not ok) but it does the opposite. I suspect that this is bad example and the code should me something like this:

```
    fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) { // res.ok <- it should be like this in my opinion but I am not sure
      throw new Error(res.error);
    }
    return res;
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Can I get some clarification since I am still in the learning process so I would like to know if I was given a bad example or the mistake something else

Comment: Yes, this is a bad example. The `.ok` property exists on the response that the `fetch()` promise fulfills with, not on the object that the `res.json()` promise fulfills with.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. Have a nice day!